# Lenovo Thinkpad T400 keyboard and port issue

Tags: ubuntu, usb, keyboard, motherboard, thinkpad

### Keyboard

I've got multiple issues with an old T400 with a new keyboard replaced last year. When I type certain characters it types double characters. For example: v is /v, 4 is 04 and so on. It does this only for certain characters, others are fine.

I tried an external keyboard and that works fine. I tried an external bootable USB and the same happens on the external USB OS(ubuntu 20) with the internal keyboard.

So i ordered a new keyboard and they sent me a T410/T420 keyboard which doesn't fit. I am returning it. But still the issue of 4 is 04, g is -g is there even with the T410/T420 keyboard. Could it be something with the motherboard?

### USB ports

Also, the T400 has two USB ports on the left, one on the right. The right port works fine with all flash drives and devices. The left ports only work with certain flash drives. External keyboards, webcam, mice only work on the right USB, nothing on the left
USB ports.

The machine is running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

What are the issues here?

Comment: Was this a Lenovo replacement part? If so, did you give Lenovo the exact FRU number of the keyboard?  If not, you need to use the FRU number and search eBay or wherever for an exact replacement. Vendor should have a return policy. I replaced the keyboard with backlight on my X230 from an eBay vendor. Works great.

Comment: No it was a generic compatible part, it's getting hard to get parts so I can't be picky about Lenovo etc. I am returning the keyboard and the return is not a problem, but it is very weird that both the bad keyboard and the soon to be returned t410 keyboard give the same errors, but external keyboard works fine!

Comment: Try these people https://www.ebay.com/b/nordic-keyboard/bn_7024939969   . I got an X230 keyboard from them.

Comment: Nordic is not a US Supplier so it may be worth asking them.

Answer (score 0):

It is the motherboard which is having issues since the keyboard worked on a R400. It is time to retire the laptop. Parts are getting hard to find.

Thanks to all who took the time to answer.